# JavaFX 2 debug css

Tags: java, css, debugging, javafx, styling

I am struggling with some css styling when working with JavaFX..

i wonder if there is any way to debug the css?

somthing like firebug or the build-in tool in chrome that show you when you press on an element what css styles applies to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look on [Scenic View](http://fxexperience.com/2012/05/introducing-scenic-view/) to see does it meet your needs a bit at least.

Comment: this is very nice tool! didnt know about it - thanks, but sadly the tool dont show what css properties are assigned to the nodes

Comment: JavaFX has the only built-in CSS file caspian.css. All selectors are defined there and overriding these selectors are enough for most use-cases (More deeper changes are done through skins). So using for example Scene Builder's CSS support for applying styles to a node, and looking which CSS properties are assigned and immediately changing them appropriately using the Netbeans's CSS builder/viewer will provide somewhat you are asking for. Check the Scene Builder tutorial.

Comment: caspian.css is a great source - although it can still be nice to have something like firebug for the css debuging.. but i guess i shouldnt be greedy :)

Answer (score 7):

In addition to using ScenicView as Uluk suggested, sometimes I also just dump the active nodes to the console after showing a Stage.  This default `toString()` for the nodes lists their css ids and style classes.

```
// debugging routine to dump the scene graph.
public  static void dump(Node n) { dump(n, 0); }
private static void dump(Node n, int depth) {
  for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++) System.out.print("  ");
  System.out.println(n);
  if (n instanceof Parent) 
    for (Node c : ((Parent) n).getChildrenUnmodifiable()) 
      dump(c, depth + 1);
}
```

Sample output:

```
BorderPane@13c3750
  Text@2e3919[styleClass=lyric-text]
  Button[id=null, styleClass=button change-lyric]
    ButtonSkin[id=null, styleClass=button change-lyric]
      ImageView@13a4e73
      LabeledText@567aef[styleClass=text]
```

There is some undocumented internal api around css processing, but nothing public.

A request to make this api public is here: [CSS Style Object Model in Java](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-17293).  You create a thing called a StyleMap and attach it to a node, which in effect creates a listener which records the css processing changes for the node occurring *after* you have added the StyleMap.

```
public void addStyleMaps(Node node, int depth) {
  node.impl_setStyleMap(FXCollections.observableMap(new HashMap<WritableValue, List<Style>>()));
  if (node instanceof Parent) {
    for (Node child : ((Parent) node).getChildrenUnmodifiable()) {
      addStyleMaps(child, depth + 1);
    }
  }
}
```

If you modify the dump routine above to =>

```
System.out.println(n + " " + node.impl_getStyleMap());
```

then the routine will also print out style changes since the stylemaps were added to the nodes.

Note the above call uses an impl_ api which is deprecated which can (and probably will) change in future JavaFX releases and will not have received the usage and testing support of the public api.

I think though, for this, you won't find it too useful until the mechanism is implemented into a graphical tool like ScenicView to interactively provide Firebug style css information.  I don't think ScenicView is opensource yet and the internal css implementation is not publicly documented, so it may be difficult to create such a tool yourself.

Comment: i do that too but that dont show information about what css properties assigned for each node and from which file / selector those properties came from

Comment: Updated answer to discuss getting more detailed css info using deprecated implementation api.