# Default JavaFX-CSS

Tags: css, javafx-8, fxml

Is there any way to see the applied CSS-Rules for JavaFX-Elements? Or there is a published reference with the default CSS-Rules available?

I would like, for example , to know the color of Toolbar's border.

Comment: Re-thinking your question, I missed a rather obvious answer before: You can use the new Scenic View (http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) application to review the properties of a node at runtime. I have so far only worked with an earlier beta, so I am not sure if it will display all CSS properties correctly, but it is intended to be the correct tool for the job.

Comment: Related with [JavaFX 2 debug css](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10734193/682495)

Comment: All the answers to this old question are outdated. Please see my answer below :  [stackoverflow.com/a/74214984/10686802](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74214984/10686802)

You can also find the default CSS (Modena) in the official repo in the skin directory where all the themes are located: [github.com/openjdk/jfx/tree/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/tree/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin) (The structure might change in the future).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The CSS file is located in javafxrt.jar at jfxrt.jar!/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/caspian/caspian.css .

Unfortunately, there is no API access to the CSS styles of an element as of now, though that is apparently being discussed for JavaFX 2.2.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will accept your answer as soon as I can

Comment: The doc has moved to http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html

Comment: And now, with JavaFX 8, the CSS reference has moved again: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html

Comment: @Gundon Here is the most recent version: https://gist.github.com/Remzi1993/23350e22a51d325ed00171c117fb66d4

Comment: @akauppi The docs have moved again: https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html since https://openjfx.io has taken over the project development.

Comment: As of this writing JavaFX 19 is the most recent version.

Comment: You can find it in the official repo in the skin directory where all the themes are located: https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/tree/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin (The structure might change in the future). But my answer below  is more detailed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74214984/10686802

Answer (score 15):

Here is the extracted caspian.css on pastebin -  http://pastebin.com/0PebD9nR

Comment: This is outdated since Modena has become the default skin, please see my answer below

Answer (score 15):

## *Modena* theme

With JavaFX 8 the default CSS is a new theme called *Modena*. See [announcement](http://fxexperience.com/2013/01/modena-new-theme-for-javafx-8/) with screenshots.

See the latest versions on the [OpenJFX site at GitHub](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx).

The modena.css for the build version Java8_91 can be found here:

https://gist.github.com/maxd/63691840fc372f22f470

If you search the css file in different JDK versions this is the way to go.

JDK below 10.0: `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar --> com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena.`

JDK for 10.0 and higher: `$JAVA_HOME/jmods/javafx.controls.jmod --> classes/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena.`

Comment: Thanks. I had to use `jmod extract` on `javafx.controls.jmod` in order to see the files.

Comment: You can find it in the official repo in the skin directory where all the themes are located: https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/tree/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin (The structure might change in the future). But my answer below  is more detailed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74214984/10686802

Answer (score 4):

From [Skinning JavaFX Applications with CSS: Default Style Sheet](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/css_tutorial/jfxpub-css_tutorial.htm#sthref4),

> The default style sheet for JavaFX applications is caspian.css, which
>   is found in the JavaFX runtime JAR file, jfxrt.jar

and

> Use the following command to extract the style sheet from the JAR file:
>
> `jar -xf jfxrt.jar com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/caspian/caspian.css`

and then just use a css viewer.

Comment: This is outdated since Modena has become the default skin, please see my answer below 

Answer (score 3):

As for the end of 2019 the default `modena.css` can be looked at official jfx github repo:

https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/tree/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena

Or you can look inside Maven [javafx-controls](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-controls). For example in `javafx-controls-13-win.jar` go to `/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/`

Comment: Nice answer with modern info.  Most of the other existing answers, even the highly voted ones, include outdated info which is now misleading for modern JavaFX implementations.

Comment: @jewelsea Indeed! I have also posted my answer below. I hope we can help others be giving up-to-date answers.

Answer (score 1):

## Modena

Modena has become the default skin for JavaFX applications.

### Default Maven dir

`%HOMEPATH%` on Windows is: `C:\Users\USERNAME`

The default maven directory is `%HOMEPATH%\.m2\repository`
And JavaFX can be found under `%HOMEPATH%\.m2\repository\org\openjfx`

### modena.css

Since JavaFX (OpenJFX) became modular the directory and file structure has changed. The most recent JavaFX version (as of this writing 19) has placed the CSS at `%HOMEPATH%\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\19` the CSS file can be found inside the following .jar file: `javafx-controls-19-win.jar` (platform specific)

I have extracted the whole modena folder and put it on GitHub: https://github.com/Remzi1993/OpenJFX-modena

And for anyone who is only interested in the core modena.css here is a public gist: https://gist.github.com/Remzi1993/23350e22a51d325ed00171c117fb66d4

## Official OpenJFX repo

You can also find out by going to their GitHub repo: https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/ and the specific directory: https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/tree/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin (The structure might change in the future). They seem to have officially moved to GitHub (finally) and the most recent documentation is also moved to their website at https://openjfx.io

### OpenJFX Docs (install guides)

- https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

### JavaFX CSS Reference Guide

- https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html